# Registration (act of recording ...)

Tags: grammaticality

According to Longman online dictionary, if "*registration*" refers to "*act of recording names and details on an official list*", it is an uncountable noun. An example by the dictionary is: "*the registration of motor vehicles*".

My question is if I have done registration more than 1 time, can I use the plural noun "registrations". For example, I registered Car A in 2016 and registered Car B in 2017, can I say: I did two registrations in 2016 and 2017 respectively. Is the use of "two registrations" correct?

Comment: [ODO](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/registration) is usually a very good place to check for count/non-count advice. It lists this sense as [count/non-count].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. ODO defines the term as a mass noun but explicitly cites a count-noun example:

> **registration** *noun*
>   (mass noun) The action or process of registering or of being registered.
>   (count noun) ‘the number of new private car registrations has increased’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/registration)